# Facebook login in - Android application

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, google-plus, facebook-login

I am trying to sign in the user using google plus and facebook. I am able to do that successfully but I want to change the design for both the buttons. For google plus I am able to use an Image button but for facebook I am not able to use the same. I am able to design and modify it but both of them are looking different. I want the user to click on the image button for facebook login and then that should check his credentials and generate the token as it does and logs in the user.

Comment: then what is the problem...what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: You want to change design of buttons??

Comment: Instead of using LoginButton which is class in facebook sdk that defines com.facebook.widget.LoginButton I want to use ImageButton doing all the functionalities. I dont want to change the design as I am able to do that and want to use ImageButton

Comment: Go to Facebook SDK then open package widgets and then loginButton, override the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to do the required task without overwriting the Login Button class. 
I was able to define the ImageButton with onClickListener which in turn will call LoginButton of facebook sdk using performClick() function present. This will in turn call all the other functionalities of the facebook login button.

Thanks